# HTTPS request connection timeout (NGINX)

Tags: centos, openssl, nginx, ssl

I tried a lot by reading different answers on Stackoverflow and other forums but unable to identify the error, can someone please check the below configuration and tell me what could be wrong?

```
server {
    server_name test.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://176.X.XX.XXX:30805;
    }
}

server {
    server_name test.domain.com;
    listen 443 ssl;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_access_test main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_error_test info;

    ssl_certificate /root/ssl/wildcard.domain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl/wildcard.domain.com.pem;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        proxy_pass http://176.X.XX.XXX:30805;
    }
}
```

I am able to access the page on http://test.domain.com but not able to get it on https://test.domain.com (instead a connection timeout), I also tried to redirect from port 80 to 443 but it didn't helped.
Since I tried a lot of different combinations of configurations

For the above configuration, the output of `nginx -t` is:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: Does something like `ss -tln` show that your server is actually listening on port 443? Also since you're passing traffic to 30805 is that port open as well?

Comment: 30805 is open, but `ss -tln` list all the ports (that I exposed off-course) but not 443. What should I do?

Comment: If you look at the NGINX logs, are you seeing any errors about that 443 server block?

Comment: No, I don't get any log for 443 block, not even access log. I got logs for :80

Comment: Nothing about your configuration looks incorrect. Can you post the output of `nginx -t`, which will test your configuration file for errors.

Comment: Added the output within question. It is fine

Comment: Try commenting out the server block for port 80 and just have the 443 one, then do `nginx -s reload` and check listening ports with SS again.

Comment: Thanks for the support @Patrick, the issue is resolved by following

Comment: No problem. You get it figured out? If you did I would recommend posting your solution as an answer so others can find it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration is fine. Issue resolved after installing `firewall-cmd` and adding a rule for port 443